How to add "finalName" to a specific Maven pom.xml on a multi-module project?
I need to add a <finalName> tag to a specific Maven pom.xml on a multi-module project but I couldn't find any recipe that fits my needs.
As there is no Maven specific recipe for this, I tried the org.openrewrite.xml.AddOrUpdateChildTag recipe, but it added the tag to all pom.xml files.
Minimal reproducible example
Goal: Add <finalName> to the batch module
Project structure:
pom.xml - parent module
|- web/pom.xml - web module
|- batch/pom.xml - batch module

OpenRewrite recipe:
  - org.openrewrite.xml.AddOrUpdateChildTag:
      parentXPath: /project//build
      newChildTag: <finalName>batch</finalName>

Result:
pom.xml - with <finalName>
|- web/pom.xml - with <finalName>
|- batch/pom.xml - with <finalName>

What I want:
pom.xml
|- web/pom.xml
|- batch/pom.xml - with <finalName>

Is there any way to restrict the file I want the recipe to run?

I removed your secondary question as we can't answer that for you.

Restricting your changes to a particular file is possible through a FindSourceFiles precondition:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/yaml-format-reference#preconditions
That's a common request, such that we did not want to add a filePattern argument to any recipe, instead opting for preconditions as a generic mechanism. I hope that helps!

Hi, Tim! I saw the preconditions, as you told me about it when I was implementing the org.openrewrite.maven.AddParentPom recipe. However I found it a bit bureaucratic as I would need to create a separate recipe just for this, right?
If you confirm this is the way, I'll test and mark as "solved".

That is the way we offer right now; it's mostly because we want recipes to be able to run across multiple repositories that we do not have a lot of options to make them specific to one particular project. Preconditions are then the way to make existing recipes project specific.
